# Exports is not defined id bundle.js. Asp .NET CORE SPA

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reactjs, redux, single-page-application

I am trying to build an app with ASP .Net Core, React and Redux. The thing is that I would like to make it using JS, not TS, so to use "dotnet new reactredux" is not an option.

Here is the error, cat't resolve: "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at bundle.js:1"

This is my webpack.config.js file:

```
     const path = require('path');
     const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
     const merge = require('webpack-merge');
     const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = (env) => {
const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);

const sharedConfig = () => ({
    stats: { modules: false },
    resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'] },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/dist/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include: /Client/,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    }
});

const clientConfig = merge(sharedConfig(), {
    entry: { 'bundle': path.join(__dirname, './Client/index.js') },
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
        path: path.join(__dirname, './wwwroot/dist'),
        publicPath: '/dist/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.css$/, use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' }) },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' },
            { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ }
        ]
    }
});

const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig(), {
    resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
    entry: { 'main-server': './Client/boot-server.js' },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: __dirname,
            manifest: require('./Client/dist/vendor-manifest.json'),
            sourceType: 'commonjs2',
            name: './vendor'
        })
    ],
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
        path: path.join(__dirname, './Client/dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel-loader', include: /Client/, exclude: /node_modules/ }
        ]
    },
    target: 'node',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map'
});

return [serverBundleConfig, clientConfig];
```

}

And this is the boot-server.js file:

```
 import * as React from 'react';
 import { createServerRenderer } from 'aspnet-prerendering';
 import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
 import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
 import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
 import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'
 import {StaticRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
 import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
 import initialState from './store/initialState';
 import App from './App';

 export default createServerRenderer(params => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const store = configureStore();
    const history = syncHistoryWithStore(createMemoryHistory(), store);

    const routerContext = {};

    const app = (
        <Provider store={store} history={history}>
            <StaticRouter context={routerContext} location={params.location.path} >
                <App/>
            </StaticRouter>    
        </Provider>
    );

    renderToString(app);

    if (routerContext.url) {
        resolve({ redirectUrl: routerContext.url });
        return;
    }

    params.domainTasks.then(() => {
        resolve({
            html: renderToString(app),
            globals: { initialState }
        });
    }, reject);
});
```

The app renders my home page but when I try to navigate somewhere else, the url changes but page is the same.

Thank you in advance.